# The null, quotes, and the completeness

Tags: riddle, mathematics

Here's a riddle:

> There are three base things: The null, Quotation marks (or simply, quotes), and the completeness.
>
> The quotes inside destroy the null, and convert to quotes, and the quotes will let the completeness be complete.
>
> But outside, the completeness slowly (but surely) gets destroyed and converts to quotes. The null can't be destroyed outside, because it's null.
>
> After that, the quotes will convert to either null or the completeness depending if the quotes start or end respectively.
>
> But this seems like it's a Golfing language, where you don't even need the even number of quotes, and will put a quote at the end when necessary.
>
> Nobody could know what was happening.

Now, there are two questions:

> What does this mean?

> What are the quotes, the null and the completeness?